# Simple regex split

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

```
string = "Peter Pan, Pete Sampras; Little Pete"
```

And I need to split it up by name:

```
split_string = ["Peter Pan", "Pete Sampras", "Little Pete"]
```

I am trying to use `re.findall` but am having a bit of trouble with it:

```
print re.findall(r'[,;]', string)
[";", ";", ";"]
```

What am I doing wrong here and how would I properly use `re.findall` here or an equivalent to split up the string?

Answer (score 2):

Using `re.split` as follows will split up your string:

```
string = "Peter Pan, Pete Sampras; Little Pete"
print re.split(r'[,;]', string)
["Peter Pan", "Pete Sampras", "Little Pete"]
```

Comment: re.split(r'\s*[,;]\s*', string) will also strip the spaces.

Comment: Also, I would avoid using the name "string" as a variable simply because it is in the standard library...

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you're not sure about the separators but are sure about the names having a space (or more) between them, you could use:

```
re.findall("\w+\s+\w+", target_string)
```

That does mean that names of only one word are skipped, as `\w` stands for a letter, and `\s` for a whitespace, and `+` indicates a greedy search for one or more elements.